# How do I get the coefficient of 3*x*y in maxima?

Tags: maxima

How do I get the coefficient of 3*x*y in maxima?
I tried `coeff(3*x*y, x*y)`.
But it only works on expressions of the form `coefficient*var^n`.

Comment: You can use `ratcoeff`

Comment: @Eelvex perhaps you submit that as an answer. FWIW I see that `ratcoeff` is an alias for `ratcoef`.